# SharePoint 2010 Team Information Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

Suddenly "My Colleague's Colleague" is appearing under some user pictures in Team Information Web Part.  Also, the user picture appears above user information not to the left of user information.

How do I remove/disable/hide "My Colleague's Colleague?"

See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting an image. This makes better. Also I recommend that if you improve the wordings. Like: what you expect and what it's behaving in brief, then I believe this Question will get reopened.